# "küssen" - usage of sharp S ("ß")

Tags: verb, spelling, eszett

The verb *"küssen"* is conjugated in second person singular, plural and in the third person with *'ß'*

> du küßt
>   er/sie/es küßt
>   ihr küßt
>   <sup>[Source](http://www.vocabulix.com/conjugation2/kuessen.html)</sup>

Is it incorrect if I use it for the others too? Also, why is it not *"küßen"* to begin with? Isn't any word with *'ss'* allowed to be replaced by *'ß'*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is spelled with double s in every case.

Have a look the answer to the question [Is there a rule that dictates whether to use the eszett (scharfes S) or double s?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/255/is-there-a-rule-that-dictates-whether-to-use-the-eszett-scharfes-s-or-double-s?rq=1).

Comment: Oh, I got the conjugation from here. That's why I asked this question. Thanks for the link by the way. Good explanation in the answers. 
http://www.vocabulix.com/conjugation2/kuessen.html

Comment: It seems like that website still uses the old rules. The new (1996) rules are simple: Short vowel is followed by double s instead of ß.

Comment: Don't forget diphthongs. They are aloways followed by ß.

Comment: There are no short diphtongs, aren't there? So "diphtongs are always followed by ß" ist more of a corollary than an additional rule.