# Words where changing “ß” to “ss” changes the meaning, e.g., “Maßen” to “Massen”

Tags: difference, meaning, spelling, eszett

*In Maßen essen* means to *to eat in moderation – in Massen essen* means to *to eat a lot.*

Are there other words whose meaning totally changes if I substitute *ß* with *ss?*

If there’s a list of similar word pairs, it would be helpful, but the question is to validate whether other words like *Massen* and *Maßen* exist.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for lists of words are usually not accepted on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Jan Only if it would be a long list. We had kind of such questions before, I think.

Comment: Change the question accordingly but it's necessary to know if there are rules and whether this is an isolated case =)

Comment: Things get funnier in Switzerland, [where ß no longer exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Switzerland_and_Liechtenstein)...

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the question on rules regarding the *ß→ss* substitution, as I fail to understand it and it seems to provoke answers about the general spelling rules for *ss* and *ß,* which was already asked about [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/255/2594). Can you please explain what you are asking about?

Comment: The question is when considering ß→ss , when will it change the meaning of the word. If so, please explain using an example or two and does that phenomenon only happen for some words, if there's a reason why it happens, it would be nice. It's more about the usage of ß→ss  more than the rules that governs it.

Comment: @alvas: What do you mean by *the usage of ß→ss?* There is *ß* and *ss* – they are distinct graphems with separate usages (except in Switzerland or when *ß* is not available). See also [Jan’s answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/25865/2594).

Comment: The linguistic term you are looking for is **minimal pair** or, in German, **Minimalpaar**. One important way to determine the phonemes and graphemes of a language is to find words that differ in one “position” only, these make minimal pairs. There are some, but not many, for ‹ß› vs. ‹ss› (and ‹ß› vs. ‹s›) with the current orthography. That means, ‹ß› forms (probably) a grapheme of its own.

Answer (score 12):

I am not aware of any such list, but I don't think it would be very long. Here are the few words that I can contribute:

- **Busse** (plural to *Bus*) vs. **Buße** (penitence; in Switzerland also a fine, but spelled *Busse* there)
- ein **Muss** (a "must") vs. ein **<strike>Muß</strike> Mus** (mush, this was a mistake by me, but i keep it as an example for an ambiguity between *ss* and *s*)
- **Rußen** (sooting, turned into a noun) vs. **Russen** (Russians)
- If there was ever a guy called "Otto Lüftung", and they would name a street for him, this would be the **Lüftungstraße**, in contrast to **[Lüftungstrasse](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/L%C3%BCftungstrasse)**

To me it looks like a random phenomenon. I don't see a pattern there or rules, beside the one that is commonly known: [when to use *ß*](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/doppel-s-und-scharfes-s) (link to German page). And don't forget that there is no *ß* in Switzerland, so you only have *Masse* and *Busse* there and need to decide from context or listening which meaning is intended.

Comment: That would be funny if someone's (vor)name is Lüftung ;P

Comment: @alvas Sure, and I am not aware of any such person, but there are all kind of funny names. It is a made-up example, but I wanted to include it because I am really bothered by all the _Strassen_ I have to see written outside of Switzerland (where it is the legal spelling).

Comment: The last example technically works with everything. If it is misspelt, I consequently will pronunce *Bahnhofs-Trasse* rather than *Bahnhof-Straße*.

Comment: @Jan "... everything that ends on 's', or would have a connecting 's' in compounds". Beside: yes. I had simply looked for a compound that I could prove to be actually in use. I am not sure about that for _Bahnhofs-Trasse_, but I am open to reasoning and more proposals (in particular if we could find a matching proper name in a phone book).

Comment: It takes a bit of streching but: ‘Wir haben zwei Varianten für die Trambahn. Einmal die Bahnhofstrasse, die zwar den Hauptbahnhof anbindet, aber laut Prognose weniger Fahrgäste transportieren wird. Zum anderen die Westtrasse, die westlich am Bahnhof durch ein dicht besiedeltes Viertel verlaufen würde.’

Comment: @Jan Replace 'Westtrasse' by 'Zentrumstrasse', and you get double success for the same effort. Nice exampe :-)

Comment: Technically, your first example is even trickier. While Buße indeed means a fine in Switzerland, in Switzerland that spelling is incorrect and should be Busse for all 3 meanings (plural to Bus, pentience, and fine)

Comment: @Jan then the Swiss will think you are one of these crazy Germans being a Besserwisser because the Swiss don't use ß.

Comment: @nalply I am perfectly aware of that and it would never cross my mind to do so in Switzerland. But I do wonder what made you assume that I would?

Comment: By the way, why does it say *fine* for Buße only in the Swiss case? Germany also knows the *Geldbuße*.

Comment: @Jan Simply because I only thought of _Bußgeld_, and because in Germany you _need_ the compound AFAIK, while in Switzerland you could write "Er musste eine Busse zahlen".

Comment: @Jan because Germans are notorious for equating the German language with Germany. Wikipedia was especially bad (but this changed in the last few years). And as you surely know there's a culture difference between Switzerland and Germany. In general the Swiss are polite, elusive and guarded compared to Germans. If a German declares his opinion in a loud voice and in an outspoken manner, the Swiss tend to smile blandly and reservedly. But of course in the newspaper comments they are as bad as everybody else.

Comment: @Jan I don't know. I didn't even know that the prefix *Geld-* is mandatory outside of Switzerland.

Comment: To add to this list: *flössen* (Konj. II of *fließen*)  and *flößen* (from *einflößen,* z. B.: “Sie flößen ein”); *Schoß* (lap) vs. *schoss* (past of *schießen*); *Ass* (ace) vs. *aß* (past of *essen*). The last two differ in captialisation but all words are capitalised at the beginning of a sentence and similar.

Comment: @Matthias there is absolutely no randomness about this. It *has* rules indeed. It can be determined by sound. A "long vowel" followed by a sharp "s" requires ß, a short vowel with a sharp  s requires "ss". A soft s always requires "s". This, of course, not an always applicable, but it's a simple rule that helps understanding.

Answer (score 8):

The premise of the question is skewed. Words containing *ss* and words containing *ß* usually have *nothing to do with each other etymologically.* Similarly to the English homophones *knight* and *night* where it would be pointless to ask ‘do the meanings of other words beginning in *n* change if I add a *k*?’

The distinction between *ß* and *ss* is a phonemic one that stems from the distinction of short and long vowels (and that of voiced and unvoiced *s*). It only originated this way because that is how our script originated from its Latin original. Modern Latin usually distinguishes between long and short vowels by adding a macron onto the former (and maybe a brevis onto the latter) but that distinction was not present in classical Latin. German handwriting can be dated back to Charlemagne and even earlier making it a rather old script that follows many more traditional rules rather than logical ones, not unlike English or French.

Other languages whose writing systems were formalised much later, such as Czech (around 1400 by Jan Hus) and Finnish (around 1500 by Mikael Agricola) chose more logical distinctions between long and short vowels that did not affect the spelling of following consonants — acute accents in Czech and vowel doubling in Finnish. German by then had gotten used to the doubled consonants following short vowels that the system was kept.

So of course, you can go around in different languages, asking, e.g. ‘Are there Czech words whose meaning dramatically changes when a vowel looses its accent?’ or ‘Are there Finnish words whose meaning drastically changes, if a single vowel is written instead of a double one?’* But I *really* don’t think either of those questions is in any way good. In fact, they would be better described as:

> Can I change a phoneme of a word to a different one to change the meaning?

And the obvious answer is *of course!*

There is one counterexample to the general rule where two words obviously derived from the same precursor: *Floß* and *floss* (although one is capitalised, being a noun, and the other is not). Both somehow derive from the verb *fließen* (*to flow*).

---

There is one single case I know of that breaks the relationship of ‘either *ß* or *ss* is correct, but never both’: The word *Geschoss* when meaning *floor* or *storey*. The ground floor can be both *Erdgeschoss* and *Erdgeschoß*. But this is because *there are two possible pronunciations of the word*, one with a short *o*, one with a long *o*.

---

Also note that this entire answer covers normal texts in Germany, Austria, Luxemburg and places in which a German-speaking minority has close ties to one of these. In Switzerland and Liechtenstein, *ß* doesn’t exist and *ss* is always written where the others distinguish between *ss* and *ß*. Also, spelling rules dictate for any variety of German that when capitalising (this includes small caps), every *ß* is replaced by *SS*.

---

*: In fact, Finnish does have a distinction which is closer to relevant: a verb ending in a long vowel is third person singular present (e.g. *tulee* he/she/it comes/is coming) and a short vowel is second person imperative (e.g. *tule* come!). But in spoken Finnish, these forms have merged.

Comment: +1 for telling me about Geschoss / Geschoß. And apparently it is the other way around with _Spaß_: according to the Duden it can also be spelled _Spass_ in Austria (and Switzerland, of course).

Comment: There is one important aspect where this questions goes beyond a simple “Can changing a phonem change a meaning?”: The fact that *ß* is replaced by *ss* is some cases, namely in small caps, all caps and Switzerland.

Comment: @Matthias: In northern Germany _Spaß_ is also often pronounced with a short _a_. Another example that was mentioned in our recent äöüß-all-in-a-single-word question is _Löß_.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Added a note on Switzerland/Liechtenstein and all caps/small caps.

Comment: @Jan: That’s not exactly what I was aiming at. I was commenting on your statement that the question is not good because it is just a special case of “Can I change a phoneme of a word to a different one to change the meaning?”. While you are correct that the ß–ss distinction is a special case of this, it is a special case of particular interest (due to small caps, all caps and Switzerland).

Comment: Erdgeschoß pronounced with long "o" is new to me, I must admint. -- Regarding capitalization of *ß*, the DUDEN suggests *specifically* for ambiguous cases (such as *Masse/Maße*) to use *SZ* for *ß* instead of *SS*. That being said, I object strongly against the idea of introducing a [capital ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E) as well as against the often observed leaving *ß* as-is ("MAßE")

Comment: New example I just found in the _Süddeutsche Zeitung_ (and confirmed by _Wahrig_): _Maß_ and _Mass_ as variant spellings for the measure of liquid capacity.

Answer (score 5):

25 years back, a very similar question was everyday business when we learned spelling at school: “When do I have to change *ß* to *ss* when building the plural form, corresponding verb, composed word, etc?” The reason is, that up until 1996, there was a spelling rule that banned *ss* at the end of the word or preceding consonants.

E.g. *Kuss* (a kiss) was spelled *Kuß* (pronounced with a short *u* nevertheless), but the plural *Küsse* and the corresponding verb *küssen* were spelled with *ss* also back then. Another example is *Adresse* (old: *Adresse*) and *Adressbuch* (old: *Adreßbuch*).

So considering the situation today, changing *ß* to *ss* always changes the meaning (at least I cannot think of a counterexample right now), but 30 years back, there was quite a list of words where it didn’t.

Btw.: The new rules didn’t apply to names. You can still find a street called *Schloßstraße* in several cities, while according to the new rules *Schlossstraße* is correct.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German.StackExchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] for any questions on how it works. Actually, your 'comment' makes for a good answer in itself; you might just want to edit it slightly, explaining the pre-1996 and post-1996 differences.

Answer (score 1):

These were the Old German Orthography rules about *ss* versus *ß*:

1. An unvoiced *s* preceeded by a short emphasised vocal is to be written as *ss*
2. If *ss* according to item 1 is at the end of a word, at the end of a composite word, or before a consonant, it turns to *ß*.
3. An unvoiced *s* preceeded by a long emphasised vocal is to be writen as *ß*.

The New German Orthography only dropped item 2.

The only point is, that Swiss dialects never wrote and never write *ß* (since 1906), it is always *ss*. This, of course, leads to possible double-readings and double-meanings as in *Massen* (because *a* can be long or short, and both words exist), same as in *Busse*

Maybe you are lucky and find a more less complete list of these words, however, these are the rules. There are real rules rather than a random list.

Comment: Note that we already have a question about the spelling rules for *ss* and *ß* [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/255/2594). If you think that your answer adds to the existing ones, feel free to post it there. Also note that I removed the part of this question that asked about the *ß→ss* substitution, which your answer probably addressed, as it was already addressed in the linked question.